# check if post request has been recieved

Tags: php, html, forms, button, http-post

i have created html form (in MyTestFile.php file) with several options, and what i want to do is to check if post request has been recievied. Or in other words when user chooses something from my combobox and pushes button "Go" then it goes to the same page and sends choosed size value and echoes the size, and then form is not visible any more when size has been set. So here is my form code which isn't really working:

```
if (isset($_POST('submit'))) {
    ?>
    <html>
    <h2>Select size:</h2>

    <form action="MyTestFile.php" method="POST">
        <div>
            <select name="SIZE">
                <option value="big">big</option>
                <option value="medium">medium</option>
                <option value="small">small</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
    </html>
<?php
} else {
    echo $_POST('submit');
//and do some stuff here

}
```

The main idea: check if post request with size has been recieved, if not - show the form, where user can choose size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` is an array, so you must use square brackets to access the elements, not parenthesies. So change this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//              ^        ^ square breackets not ()
```

Secondly your submit button doesn't have a name, so your `isset()` check will never be true. Give it a name:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
```

Or use the `SIZE` select in the isset check:

```
if (isset($_POST['SIZE'])) {
```

Finally your isset check needs reversing, in order to show the form when the post value is not present:

```
if (!isset($_POST['SIZE'])) {
//  ^ not operator to reverse the check
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you tried so here you go:

Just add an exclamation mark before isset, add a name to the submit button and replace those parentheses with square brackets.

```
  if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
               {
                     ?>
                       <html>
                           <h2>Select size:</h2>          
                            <form action="MyTestFile.php" method="POST"><div>
                                <select name="SIZE">
                                 <option value="big">big</option>
                                  <option value="medium">medium</option>
                                  <option value="small">small</option>
                                </select>                               
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
                            </form>
                       </html>
               <?php
               }
               else 
               {
                echo $_POST['size'];
//and do some stuff here

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[` don't use `(` in `$_POST` method. Because `$_POST` is array so use square brackets. Use same `submit` as name in submit button.

`$_POST['submit']` instead of `$_POST('submit')`

and add `!` (Not Set) in `if` condition, use below code,

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
  // Your Form Code
}
else{
  print_r($_POST);
}
```